Unable to connect to newrelic using Opentelemetry
I am trying to send tracing data to newrelic using opentelemetry-otlp via http
Below is code snippet that I am using
fn main() -> {
   let result = init_tracer_provider();
   
   globa::set_tracer_provider(result.unwrap().clone());

   let tracer = tracer_provider.tracer("my-service-tracer");
   let telemetry_layer = tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(tracer);

   let subscriber = Registry:default()
                      .with(telemetry_layer);
   subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber).expect("Some message");
}


fn init_tracer_provider() -> Result<sdktrace::TracerProvider, TraceError> {
    let http_client = hyper_client_config::HyperClient::default();
    opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .with_exporter(
            http_exporter()
                .with_protocol(Protocol::HttpJson)
                .with_endpoint("https://trace-api.newrelic.com/v1/traces")
                .with_headers(get_http_headers(api_key)
                .with_http_client(http_client),
        )
        .with_trace_config(Config::default().with_resource(RESOURCE.clone()))
        .install_batch(opentelemetry_sdk::runtime::Tokio)
}

fn get_http_headers(api_key : &String) -> HashMap<String,String> {
    let mut headers = HashMap::new();
    headers.insert(String::from_str("Api-Key"), String::from_str(api_key); 
    headers.insert(String::from_str("Content-Type"), String::from_str("application/json");
    headers.insert(String::from_str("Data-Format"), String::from_str("newrelic);  
    headers
}

Another file that maintains hyper_client_config.rs. This I am referring to for implementing trait HttpClient required by with_http_client
use async_trait::async_trait;
use bytes::Bytes;
use http::{Request, Response};
use http_body_util::{BodyExt, Full};
use hyper_util::{
    client::legacy::{
        connect::{Connect, HttpConnector},
        Client,
    },
    rt::TokioExecutor,
};
use opentelemetry_http::{HttpClient, HttpError, ResponseExt};

pub struct HyperClient<C> {
    inner: hyper_util::client::legacy::Client<C, Full<Bytes>>,
}

impl Default for HyperClient<HttpConnector> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Client::builder(TokioExecutor::new()).build_http(),
        }
    }
}

impl<C> std::fmt::Debug for HyperClient<C> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("HyperClient")
            .field("inner", &self.inner)
            .finish()
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl<C: Connect + Clone + Send + Sync + 'static> HttpClient for HyperClient<C> {
    async fn send(&self, request: Request<Vec<u8>>) -> Result<Response<Bytes>, HttpError> {
        let request = request.map(|body| Full::new(Bytes::from(body)));

        let (parts, body) = self
            .inner
            .request(request)
            .await?
            .error_for_status()?
            .into_parts();
        let body = body.collect().await?.to_bytes();

        Ok(Response::from_parts(parts, body))
    }
}

But I get this error in the logs
Opentelemetry trace error occurred. client error (Connect)

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-rust/blob/main/opentelemetry-otlp/examples/basic-otlp-http/src/main.rs
I am referring to this github code. Can someone help. Is there anything I am missing

.with_endpoint("https://trace-api.newrelic.com/v1/traces") looks wrong, for otlp newrelic end point



Environment
gRPC
HTTP
Endpoint
Supported ports




US OTLP
✅
✅
https://otlp.nr-data.net
443, 4317, 4318


EU OTLP
✅
✅
https://otlp.eu01.nr-data.net
443, 4317, 4318


US FedRAMP OTLP
✅
✅
https://gov-otlp.nr-data.net
443, 4317, 4318


(See FedRAMP compliance for more information)






Infinite tracing
✅
✅
https://{trace-observer}
443



Example rust code
fn init_tracer() -> Result<trace::Tracer, TraceError> {
    opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .with_exporter(
            opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
                .http()
                .with_endpoint("https://otlp.nr-data.net/v1/traces")
                .with_headers(HashMap::from([(
                    "api-key".to_string(),
                    "LICENSEKEY".to_string(),
                )]))
        )
        .with_trace_config(
            trace::config().with_resource(Resource::new(vec![KeyValue::new(
                opentelemetry_semantic_conventions::resource::SERVICE_NAME,
                "rust-otlp-newrelic-tracing",
            )])),
        )
        .install_batch(runtime::Tokio)
}

Check the git repo in the reference
Reference:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/opentelemetry/best-practices/opentelemetry-otlp/
https://github.com/Tirslo/rust-opentelemetry-examples/blob/main/rust-otlp-newrelic/src/main.rs

